What is the CPU Usage of each Ethereum Clients in a node?
I am trying to find out what is the average CPU usage of Execution and Consensus Clients in each round (12 secs) of consensus.
As far my knowledge each consensus round is divided into three 4 secs slots. Does a Execution Client has to run the entire 12 secs (same for Consensus Client)?

The CPU usage depends on the block content and what kind of a server you have. There is no generic answer.
For a particular server, you can run Ethereum and see what the CPU usage is. Furthermore different Ethereum clients offer diagnostics like log output to give you more information.

Does generally the consensus process needs execution client in the last 2 phase of the 12 seconds consensus slot? (Because the last 2 phase has nothing to do with transaction execution)
Ref1 - https://www.paradigm.xyz/2023/04/mev-boost-ethereum-consensus#:~:text=for%20block%20production.-,Slots%20%26%20sub%2Dslot%20periods,-In%20Ethereum%20PoS
Ref2 - https://www.blocknative.com/blog/anatomy-of-a-slot

If you have another question please use Ask Question button instead of trying to discuss it in comments.
Please add sufficient context and background information for your question (what you are asking, why are you asking).
